# Prime number C++ program

Tags: c++, primes

I am not sure whether I should ask here or programmers but I have been trying to work out why this program wont work and although I have found some bugs, it still returns "x is not a prime number", even when it is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


  bool primetest(int a) {
 int i;
 //Halve the user input to find where to stop dividing to (it will remove decimal point as it is an integer)
 int b = a / 2;
 //Loop through, for each division to test if it has a factor (it starts at 2, as 1 will always divide)
 for (i = 2; i < b; i++) {
     //If  the user input has no remainder then it cannot be a prime and the loop can stop (break)
     if (a % i == 0) {
           return(0);
           break;
     }
     //Other wise if the user input does have a remainder and is the last of the loop, return true (it is a prime)
              else if ((a % i != 0) && (i == a -1)) {
          return (1);
          break;
     }
 }   
}

 int main(void) {
int user;
cout << "Enter a number to test if it is a prime or not: ";
cin >> user;
if (primetest(user)) {
                   cout << user << " is a prime number.";
}
else  {
      cout << user<< " is not a prime number.";
}
cout << "\n\nPress enter to exit...";
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is too localised (in which case could you suggest where I should ask such specific questions?)

I should add that I am VERY new to C++ (and programming in general)

This was simply intended to be a test of functions and controls.

Comment: Give us some examples of when it doesn't work.

Comment: why not do this... add a return(1) statement outside the for loop and remove the else if statement, that way if the loop is completed and the function has not returned the number is going to be prime.

Comment: Some right answers are already posted below, but I would like to add some general things. The parentesises arround your return value are redundant. The value after return will always be calulated before returning. The parentesises in ((a % i != 0) && (i == a -1)) arround the two checks are also reduntant, although these are not necessarely bad, because they might make it easier to read. As you are a beginning programmer, I would like you to know this. Next, you do not check if the input provided is actually a number, so this might crash if you input something else.

Answer (score 5):

`i` can never be equal to `a - 1` - you're only going up to `b - 1`.  `b` being `a/2`, that's never going to cause a match.

That means your loop ending condition that would return 1 is never true.

In the case of a prime number, you run off the end of the loop.  That causes undefined behaviour, since you don't have a `return` statement there.  Clang gave a warning, without any special flags:

```
example.cpp:22:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

If your compiler didn't warn you, you need to turn on some more warning flags.  For example, adding `-Wall` gives a warning when using GCC:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘bool primetest(int)’:
example.cpp:22: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Overall, your prime-checking loop is much more complicated than it needs to be. Assuming you only care about values of `a` greater than or equal to `2`:

```
bool primetest(int a)
{
    int b = sqrt(a); // only need to test up to the square root of the input

    for (int i = 2; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
           return false;
   }

   // if the loop completed, a is prime
   return true;
}
```

If you want to handle all `int` values, you can just add an `if (a < 2) return false;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. You are using this expression `(i == a -1))` which can never be true as Carl said.

For example:-

```
 If a = 11

 b = a/2 = 5  (Fractional part truncated)
```

So you are running loop till `i<5`. So `i` can never be equal to `a-1` as max value of i in this case will be 4 and value of `a-1` will be 10

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just checking till square root. But below is some modification to your code to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool primetest(int a) {
int i;
//Halve the user input to find where to stop dividing to (it will remove decimal point as it is an integer)
int b = a / 2;
//Loop through, for each division to test if it has a factor (it starts at 2, as 1 will always divide)
for (i = 2; i <= b; i++) {
 //If  the user input has no remainder then it cannot be a prime and the loop can stop (break)
 if (a % i == 0) {
       return(0);

 }
}
//this return invokes only when it doesn't has factor
return 1;   
}

int main(void) {
  int user;
  cout << "Enter a number to test if it is a prime or not: ";
  cin >> user;
  if (primetest(user)) {
               cout << user << " is a prime number.";
  }
  else  {
     cout << user<< " is not a prime number.";
  }

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
//Prime Numbers generation in C++
//Using for loops and conditional structures
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 2;       //start from 2
long long int b = 1000;     //ends at 1000

for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{

 for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
 {
    if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j))    //Condition for not prime
        {
            break;
        }

    if (j==i)             //condition for Prime Numbers
        {
              cout << i << endl;

        }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    int i,j,x,box;
    for (i=10;i<=99;i++)
    {
        box=0;
        x=i/2;
        for (j=2;j<=x;j++)
            if (i%j==0) box++;
        if (box==0) cout<<i<<" is a prime number";
        else cout<<i<<" is a composite number";
        cout<<"\n";
        getch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for the Finding Prime numbers till any user entered number.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

main() 
{
 int num, i, countFactors;
 int a;
 cout << "Enter number " << endl;
 cin >> a;

 for (num = 1; num <= a; num++)
 {
  countFactors = 0;
  for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)
  {
   //if a factor exists from 2 up to the number, count Factors
   if (num % i == 0)
   {
    countFactors++;    
   }
  }

  //a prime number has only itself as a factor
  if (countFactors == 1)
  {
   cout << num << ", ";
  }
 }

 getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a Sieving algorithm, such as the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). This is a very fast method that works exceptionally well.

```
bool isPrime(int number){
  if(number == 2 || number == 3 | number == 5 || number == 7) return true;
  return ((number % 2) && (number % 3) && (number % 5) && (number % 7));
}
```